# jQuery datatables pagination - problem with sending form on multiple pages

Tags: jquery, forms, flask, datatables, pagination

I'm using DataTables in my flask based webpage. The whole content of the table with pages is a form. When i submit it, in request.form I have only the page that was selected during submitting, but I want to receive every page.

I've already made something like this in JS, which stores every input and select from every page in variable `data`. I struggle with sending that data as a post request in normal format like form will be normally sent.

```
$('input[name="submit_form"]').click(function() {
    var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
});
```

Comment: One way of doing it is to destroy the datatable, submit the form & build the datatable again if needed.